# Mule 4 SFTP Timeout in Cloudhub

Tags: mule, sftp, mule-studio, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I have a Mule 4 flow which connects to a SFTP location to read files, and perform a set of operations.
This works fine when I run the project from Anypoint Studio. However when I deploy this, I see the following error when the projects gets deployed to cloudhub:

**Connectivity test failed for config 'SFTP_Config'. Application deployment will continue.
Error was: Could not establish SFTP connection with host: '**.**.**.***' at port: '22' - timeout: socket is not established
org.mule.runtime.api.connection.
ConnectionException: Could not establish SFTP connection with host: '**.**.**.***' at port: '22' - timeout: socket is not established at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.connection.ErrorTypeHandlerConnectionProviderWrapper.lambda$connect$0(ErrorTypeHandlerConnectionProviderWrapper.java:70)
at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)**

My SFTP connection config is as shown below:

```
<sftp:config name="SFTP_Config" doc:name="SFTP Config" doc:id="3cac96f7-4985-48eb-a4fc-77a312a6dc22" >
    <sftp:connection workingDir="${sftp.basepath}" host="${sftp.host}" username="${sftp.user}" password="${sftp.password}" port="${sftp.port}">
        <reconnection >
            <reconnect frequency="20000" count="5" />
        </reconnection>
    </sftp:connection>
</sftp:config>
```

Am I missing something in the connection configuration. Or is the error due to something else?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Usually communication will fail from CloudHub when it is a private server, not accessible from the public Internet, or access requires a whitelist from the server side.

You can test if there is network connectivity deploying a test application to perform tests as described here: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Network-connectivity-testing

In the first case, you need to [setup a VPN from CloudHub to the network](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/vpn-about) where the SFTP server resides. You may also need to [setup the internal DNS](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/resolve-private-domains-vpc-task) if the host name is not public or not an IP.

For the second you can setup a [public static IP](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/deploying-to-cloudhub#static-ips-tab-settings) for the worker where the application is deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your sftp.host is available from cloud.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, could you please let me know how to verify the same?